# <f:ajax> multiple call of Java method - how to do it only once?

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I'm using ajax to call java method `bean.findDetail()`. If the method finds detailItem object in database, the rest of inputTexts is rendered.

```
<h:inputText id="worker" value="#{bean.item.id}">
 <f:ajax event="change" render="name" listener="#{bean.findDetail}"/>
 <f:ajax event="change" render="surname"/>
 <f:ajax event="change" render="age"/>
</h:inputText>

<h:panelGroup>
 <h:inputText id="name" value="#{bean.detailItem.name}" disabled="true"/>
 <h:inputText id="surname" value="#{bean.detailItem.surname}" disabled="true"/>
 <h:inputText id="age" value="#{bean.detailItem.age}" disabled="true"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Everything is working fine, but method is called three times!

Is there some way to render all three inputText at once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just place space seperated values in render element

```
<h:inputText id="worker" value="#{bean.item.id}">
 <f:ajax event="change" render="name surname age" listener="#{bean.findDetail}"/>
</h:inputText>
```

Comment: Oooops, thank you!! I've tried it only by comma separated (render="name, surname, age") :)